# SubmitForm is not working in power apps

Tags: powerapps

I am creating  Power Apps from that user can fill the record and record should get saved in dynamics 365.

**Problem:** Whenever I submit the form I get a error stating "Field is Required" or "An entry is required or has an invalid value" and form gets reloaded, whereas I have filled data in all the fields.

**Screenshots:**
[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have come across this error, sometimes resubmitting the form works (but is not ideal).  Otherwise, are you sure there are no hidden fields that also require a value?  Finally, you can test by creating a new record with the Collect function to confirm the required fields.

Comment: @Meneghino can you please explain in detail or give an example of how u  solved  your error. I am stuck on this

Comment: The error has simply appeared on a couple of apps on previous versions, and I never understood why.  The first update submission raises the error, while all subsequent submission work.  All apps I have produced in the last couple of months have not given this error.  Please be aware that date columns have issues, for example see the second point in [this post](https://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/2017/09/28/powerapps-and-azure-sql-database-current-issues/).

Comment: @Meneghino when i select the record from Browse Screen and edit and save that, those changes I can see in CRM  for that particular record. But when i try to create a new record and save that it shows that error which i mentioned earlier.

Comment: then I suggest that you try to Collect a new record to see if the issue is with the form or with the data source.  I can help by Skype if needed, my handle is baizini

Comment: can you send me your id where i can share screenshots related to this

Comment: Does this issue only affect new records? if you are editing it is unaffected and works as it should?